# Ambiguous use of subscript compiler error

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3

The function below is for `ELCImagePicker` to pick multiple images and I added my code to, the code used to run probably and suddenly after installing Parse SDK it gave error

> "Ambiguous use of subscript"

at this line of code :

```
if let image = item[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
```

Code:

```
func elcImagePickerController(_ picker: ELCImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [Any]!) {

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    var i = 0
    var z = 0

    var imageViews = [Any]() // array of any object used to save the selected imagesviews to it so we can display it on the viewcontroller
    for item in info as [AnyObject]
    {
        z += 0 //we used z = +0 as the arrays always starts at index 0 not 1
        i += 1  //we used another var i += 1 as UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage starts at 1

        if let image = item[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
        {
            imagearray.insert(image, at: z) // array of images to be used in "Saved" function below to save the images selected to core data

            image_view = UIImageView(image: image)

            let currentImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 130 + (i * 10), y: 50 + (i * 5), width: 50, height: 100))
            currentImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            currentImageView.image = image_view.image
            imageViews.append(currentImageView)
        }

    }
    var y = 0
    var imageview: AnyObject
    for _ in imageViews as [Any] {
        imageview = imageViews[y] as AnyObject
        view.addSubview(imageview as! UIView)
        y += 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [search on the error](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+Ambiguous+use+of+subscript) before posting. This has been covered many times before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell compiler the type of `item`, so instead of casting `info` array to `[AnyObject]` type cast it to `[[String:Any]]`.

```
if let imagesArray = info as? [[String:Any]] {
    for item in imagesArray {
        if let image = item[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
            //Access image instance 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Nirva D - great, it worked but do you know why it appeared suddenly and did not happen before - I just  want to understand

Comment: From Swift 3 you need to tell the compiler its type before using it and you are working with Swift 3,Right?

Comment: yes but till an hour ago it was working and 20 minutes ago this error appeard

Comment: @rania In Swift 3 it is working previous? or you are migrating from Swift 2.3 to Swift 3?

Comment: no I didnot migrate I was working on swift 3 all the time - I only installed Parse SDK and this error appeared

Comment: @rania Don't know why this is related to Parse SDK?